# how to show data from two related tables, with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables one called "**Events**" and another one "**Dependences**", a dependency can have several events, that is the relation between them, what I try to do is show the data of an event, but also show the data of the dependency to which is related.

This is my controller where I bring the event:

```
class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
    public function evento($slug){
    $event = Event::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    return view('evento', compact('event'));
}
```

This is the event model:

```
class Event extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'events';

    protected $fillable = [
        'admin_id', 'dependence_id', 'place_id', 'name', 'slug', 'excerpt', 'body', 'status', 'file'
    ];

    public function dependences(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Dependence', 'dependence_id');
    }
```

dependence model:

```
class Dependence extends Model
{
    protected $table = "dependences";

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'slug'
    ];

    public function events(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Event');
    }
```

so I try to show it in the view:

```
@foreach($event->dependences as $dependence)
                <a href="#">
                {{$dependence->name}}
                </a>
                @endforeach
```

but I get this error: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

these are the tables in the database:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbBYR.png)

the routes are fine, but I do not know what the problem is, I hope for your help, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should access directly, as:

```
$event->dependence->name;
```

Since, `belongsTo` relationship brings one item.

Also add a check to see if the object is null, as in:

```
@if($event->dependece)
    $event->dependence->name;
@endif
```

You could also use an `@else` in case you want to manage the null case somehow

Comment: yes, I think the same, but I have this error: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Comment: change your relationship name too, to dependence

Comment: I changed the name of the relationship and it worked!
why does that happen?

Comment: It works for 2 reasons, i assume you are printing some kind of table, some events may not have a dependence set, so the if checks if the object is empty, preventing the error. And second, the name of the relationship is the name you would use when invoking on the blade template and controllers. By standard, you set one to many and many to many relations with plural names and one to one with singular names. you could also name them "asdfgh" and access it like that but it's no standard.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one dependency for every event. So you no need to use foreach.

```
$events->dependency->name
```

And you should change the relationship name from `dependences` to `dependency`.

```
class Event extends Model
{
    public function dependency()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Dependence', 'dependence_id');
    }
}
```

In view:

```
@foreach($events as $event)
   <a href="#"> {{ $event->dependency->name }} </a>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I already tried this, but I have this error: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Comment: wow great man!, why does that happen? Why did I have to change the name of the relationship?